# ASP.NET Bootstrap .container width stuck at 1170px

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I am trying to widen the bootstrap .container for my ASP.NET C# application which is intended only for desktops. I have a few critical Gridviews with more than 12 columns for which the text is getting crushed because of the max 1170px width.

There are lots of threads on this subject including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224823/bootstrap-framework-not-responsive-for-asp-net-webform) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907915/customizing-max-width-value-for-bootstrap-container) which are exactly what I'm trying to do.

Yet, I can't figure out how to get the .container max-width to stretch wider than 1170px. I changed line 1246 in the bootstrap.css file to be:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
      max-width: 1900;
  }
```

I've forced width: to be 1500px. I've tried !important, I've tried all of the thread suggestions in site.css. I've even commented out the max-width: 1170px; in bootstrap.css completely, and in bootstrap.min.css. But when I load the page in my browser (Chrome) and inspect the webpage (F12) and drill down into the .container the max-width is still 1170px. I can mouse-wheel and increase the attribute in real-time in the browser inspection so the attribute is definitely responding. But I can't find this 1170px setting anywhere else.

I've searched through the chain of files the site.master, css files, the cs files, the aspx files looking for the text "1170" but there's none left after commenting out what I could find.

Can anyone help?

This is bootstrap 3.0.0

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with you.
In my case, I try to set "max-width" and "margin" in ".body-content" like below. And it works.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.body-content {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    max-width: none;
}
```